# How should I fix the configure.yaml file?

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, boost, yaml

I am trying to install hpctoolkit using spack. In order to do that, I executed :

```
git clone https://github.com/spack/spack.git
cd spack/share/spack
source setup-env.sh 
spack fetch -D hpctoolkit
spack install hpctoolkit
```

In order to see the available compilers, I need to look at the content of compilers.yaml.
Here is its content:

```
lcompilers:
- compiler:
    spec: clang@10.0.0
    paths:
      cc: /usr/bin/clang
      cxx: /usr/bin/clang++
      f77: null
      fc: null
    flags: {}
    operating_system: ubuntu20.04
    target: x86_64
    modules: []
    environment: {}
    extra_rpaths: []
- compiler:
    spec: clang@7.0.1
    paths:
      cc: null
      cxx: null
      f77: /usr/bin/flang
      fc: /usr/bin/flang
    flags: {}
    operating_system: ubuntu20.04
    target: x86_64
    modules: []
    environment: {}
    extra_rpaths: []
    
- compiler:
    spec: gcc@10.2.0
    paths:
      cc: /usr/bin/gcc-10
      cxx: null
      f77: /usr/bin/gfortran-10
      fc: /usr/bin/gfortran-10
    flags: {}
    operating_system: ubuntu20.04
    target: x86_64
    modules: []
    environment: {}
    extra_rpaths: []
```

As you can see here I have 2 compilers which are clang (2 instances) and gcc.
I thought the file is properly written until I executed this command:

```
spack compiler list
```

which gave me the following error:

```
==> Available compilers
==> Error: /home/hakim/.spack/linux/compilers.yaml:1: Additional properties are not allowed ('lcompilers' was unexpected)
```

The file worked perfectly before I modified it. I deleted a part which represents an other version of `gcc` which is `gcc@9.3.0` (Spack notation).

The error mentions that 'lcompilers' was unexpected but I'm quite sure it was there before I modify the file. All I did was deleting the old version of gcc.

Comment: I think you should try removing the "l" to get "compilers" instead of "lcompilers"

Comment: @Linkthehero2222 You are the best !! Thanks a lot.

Comment: haha no problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing `lcompilers` to `compilers`. It's just a typo error.